# Invisible texture of character on new Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

Recently I installed Unity version of 2022.3.12.
I downloaded [Starter Assets > Third Person Controller].
And I added [Prefab > PlayerArmature] into Hierarchy.

The character's skin is pink.
I searched google.com and I found a solution.
It's setting menu [Edit > Render Pipeline > Universal Pipeline]
But I can not find this menu item on the latest version of Unity.

I tried other asset (Hungry Zombie). It is showing correct texture.
How can I show texture on character?

[image]

Comment: are you running urp or hdrp? which version of unity, like everyone they move menu options.. second, is the material assigned? unity paints things pink if a) it cant find the shader, b) hates the material